# Adding a computed column to an ActiveRecord query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, calculated-columns

I am running a query using a scope and some conditions.  Something like this:

```
conditions[:offset] = (options[:page].to_i - 1) * PAGE_SIZE unless options[:page].blank?    
conditions[:limit] = options[:limit] ||= PAGE_SIZE
scope = Promo.enabled.active
results = scope.all conditions
```

I'd like to add a computed column to the query (at the point when I'm now calling scope.all).  Something like this:

(ACOS(least(1,COS(0.71106459055501)*COS(-1.2915436464758)*COS(RADIANS(addresses.lat))*COS(RADIANS(addresses.lng))+
 COS(0.71106459055501)*SIN(-1.2915436464758)*COS(RADIANS(addresses.lat))*SIN(RADIANS(addresses.lng))+
 SIN(0.71106459055501)*SIN(RADIANS(addresses.lat))))*3963.19) as accurate_distance

Is there a way to do that without just using find_by_sql and rewriting the whole existing query?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to add this computed quantity to the SELECT part of the statement, or as part of a condition?  Also, what's the database?

Comment: As part of the select statement

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, use this:

```
conditions = Hash.new
conditions[:select] = "#{Promo.quoted_table_name}.*, (ACOS(...)) AS accurate_distance")
conditions[:offset] = (options[:page].to_i - 1) * PAGE_SIZE unless options[:page].blank?    
conditions[:limit] = options[:limit] ||= PAGE_SIZE
scope = Promo.enabled.active
results = scope.all conditions
```

Note the new :select - that tells ActiveRecord what columns you want returned. The returned object in results will have a #accurante_distance accessor. Unfortunately, ActiveRecord is dumb and won't be able to infer the column's type. You can always add a method:

```
class Promo
  def accurate_distance
    raise "Missing attribute" unless has_attribute?(:accurate_distance)
    read_attribute(:accurate_distance).to_f # or instantiate a BigDecimal
  end
end
```

See [#has_attribute](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-i-has_attribute%3F) for details.

Comment: Since this was in 2011 wondering Is this still the preferred way of doing this in Rails4?